# In Spring's RequestMapping, is {parameter:.+} any different than {parameter}

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm looking at some Spring code that uses a RequestMapping like so:

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{bar:.+}")
```

Is this functionally any different than the following?

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{bar}")
```

From what I can tell the RegExp is always applied to the segment between slashes, so the two should be equivalent (although maybe .+ might say "non-empty?).

I suppose another way to phrase the question might be:

Is Spring's `{bar}` equivalent to `{bar:.*}` or `{bar:.+}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verified using a small test - it is `@RequestMapping("/foo/{bar:.+}")` the reason is if it is `.*`, it means that `/foo/` and `/foo/something` will map to the same request mapped method, which it will not.

Answer (score 1):

`.+` -> says 1 or more
`.*` -> would say 0 or more...

Comment: But is Spring's `{bar}` equivalent to `{bar:.*}` or `{bar:.+}`?